# Change the column value if it fits another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello to every poeple of stackoverflow community
i want to ask something to you

[image]

Comment: that is rreally hard to understand, and please don't use images.

Comment: i am aware of that. i wish i could know English like native

Comment: For your own sanity, please **NEVER** use SQL keywords as table or column names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type i don't know how can i compare it and to what

> ```
> CREATE TABLE spawnhist (
>   `npctempladeld` INTEGER,
>   `count` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO spawnhist
>   (`npctempladeld`, `count`)
> VALUES
>   ('100', '1'),
>   ('200', '1'),
>   ('300', '1');
>
> CREATE TABLE npc (
>   `npcid` INTEGER,
>   `type` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO npc
>   (`npcid`, `type`)
> VALUES
>   ('100', 'L2Monster'),
>   ('200', 'L2NPC'),
>   ('300', 'L2PET');
> ```

> ```
> Update spawnhist SET `count` = `count` +1 
> WHERE npctempladeld IN (SELECT `npcid` FROM npc WHERE type = 'L2Monster')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM spawnhist
> ```
>
> ```
> npctempladeld | count
> ------------: | ----:
>           100 |     2
>           200 |     1
>           300 |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ed998b592ccc31e34b76a3e42a78b58)*

Comment: Update spawnhist SET `count` = `count` +1 
WHERE npctempladeld IN (SELECT `npcid` FROM npc WHERE type = 'L2Monster')

Thank you so much that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Something like, ( what I understood at first glance)

My code is based on oracle but I believe it works the same in MySQL. Please try.

```
 Update spawnlist sl
        Set count = 2
  Where exists (select 1
                   from npc nc
                where nc.npc_id = sl.npc_templadeId
                    and nc.type = 'L2Monster')
```

Comment: i am getting this syntax error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
> Time: 0s

Comment: I checked with fiddle and it works. Just check the names are correct or not? Otherwise I would provide fiddle reference